FeynArts/FeynCalc operator vertex insersion
I'm trying to generate diagrams with FeynArts for use in FeynCalc that have a single insertion of a given operator (say a pseudoscalar quark bilinear $\bar{q}i\gamma^5 q$). FeynArts has Vertex Function topologies, but these don't seem to be what I'm looking for.
Going off of this question it seems the way to proceed is to add the operator to the Feynman rules of the theory using FeynRules. If this is the case is there a way to restrict to a single instance of the operator in each diagram? Say, give it a coupling and restrict to first order.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
